# How can I get my phone to boot again?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.2-jelly-bean, boot

I have a Samsung Galaxy Mini (GT-S5570) and the ROM I'm using is CM10.1, I was messing with the developer options and I saw an option called "simulate second screen" and I  clicked that and selected 720 then it froze. I rebooted it and stops at the end of the boot animation and get stuck there.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try "Volume Up + Menu Button + Power Button"? 
That should get you to Recovery Mode and you should have an option there to Factory Reset your phone.

Comment: And if I want to have my data saved?

Comment: If you make a factory reset, then only the apps will be deleted, and if you have contacts or your phone. same goes for mms. If you sync your contacts with google then you will not lose any contacts. I don't know another way, sry.

Comment: Yep, it's a shame, well, I had to do factory reset. Thanks for reply anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Hold down the volume down button while booting and go into 'safe mode'. Go to the developer menu and turn it off. Reboot.

Comment: Hah, you can't boot my model into `safe mode`. Only withing the OS.